# SQL/Hive - dynamic date range - half month that has passed before today's date

Tags: sql, hive

I want to set dynamic date parameters for my Hive query. I want to get the half month that has passed before today's date. How can I do that? I am not sure if i can do `case when` in `SET hivevar:`
e.g.

```
if current_date = '2022-10-04', then I want to set start_dt = '2020-09-16' and end_dt = '2020-09-30'
if current_date = '2022-03-04', then I want to set start_dt = '2020-02-16' and end_dt = '2020-02-28'
if current_date = '2022-10-16', then I want to set start_dt = '2020-10-01' and end_dt = '2020-10-15'
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to set dynamic parameters. Using if you can easily achieve it.

For each case you can calculate them using year(),month(), add_month() functions. to_date can be used to convert to a date. Pls test below sql and let me know.

Logic for start dt is -
If curr date is <16, the use 16th of last month else use first day of curr month.
Similarly end dt is also calculated.

```
select
to_date(
if (day(current_date())<16, concat(year(add_months(current_date(),-1)),'-',month(add_months(current_date(),-1)),'-','16'),
concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-','01')
)
) as star_dt,

if (day(current_date())<16, 
last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)),
to_date(
concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(current_date()),'-','15')
)
) as end_dt
```

Pls test the sqls out. If you face issues, pls enclose `year`,`month` output with `cast(... as string)`.